# Rails server doesn't shutdown with CTR+C in Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm using the default "rails server" command to launch a web server from the command line. For some reason, neither  CTR+C nor CTR+Z seem to shutdown the server.

The web server appears to be running normally. Closing the terminal does shutdown the web server. CTR+C has the normal copy behavior in other applications. I'm having this problem when I launch the web server from the Windows command prompt and PowerShell windows.

Is this expected behavior, what could be my problem, or what can I do to investigate further?

Comment: This guy has the same problem as you: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5360. It is not expected behaviour.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> or <kbd>Break</kbd> to stop rails server from the MS-DOS command prompt

Comment: Sounds great but if I am using my mac with parallels I don't have a windows keyboard.  What is the equivalent to Ctrl + Pause with the mac keyboard?

Comment: @drhenner - I had the same problem. Open up Windows' On-Screen Keyboard to do it! Not much better than closing the prompt and restarting though...

Comment: On my Dell laptop, neither these keys or others suggested worked. Had to start using "ruby script\rails server", then CTRL-C works.

Comment: I've found I need to delete <app>\tmp\pids\server.pid before I can restart. Perhaps something new in rails, but may help others.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a notebook and do not have <kbd>Pause</kbd> and <kbd>Break</kbd> buttons, then you can try to stop rails server by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. It works for my Lenovo.

Answer (score 3):

When I launched rails server from Powershell ISE I cannot shut down the server with any of the above commands. And just ending the task doesn't work - I also have to end the ruby task. Plain powershell works fine for me, that is what I use.

**Edit**: I am using Windows 8.

On Windows use `ruby script\rails server` and you should be fine and be able to use Ctrl+C. Otherwise you will have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> which has been stated by many on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**On Windows, typically you  use `ruby script/rails server` and you should be fine and be able to use Ctrl+C. Otherwise you will have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> which has been stated by many on this site.**

In other words, use `ruby script/rails server` instead of just `rails server` if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> is unavailable to you.

Answer (score 2):

If the tips above don't work for you try this:

In each rails application there is a folder tmp\pids

```
cd tmp
cd pids
```

In this folder there is a file server.pid

```
dir
```

Delete it.

```
del *.pid
dir
```

then return back to the original folder of your rails app where you normally run the rails s command.

```
cd..\..
rails s
```

This worked for me...

However I don't know why deleting that file worked. I believe its because my computer shut down improperly when the WEBrick server was running and it did not have a chance to remove this file. But this is just a guess. I dont actually know for sure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Ctrl + Break option would work if Ctrl C or  Ctrl Z doesn't. My Ruby command prompt won't respond to either of those and my laptop doesn't have a 'Break' key mapped in so I just closed the command window ;)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works for me.  I was having the same problem exiting the server from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Its <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAUSE</kbd> for me.

First time I've ever used the <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> key in 20 years of using Windows... :S

If you don't have a dedicated <kbd>PAUSE</kbd> key then it might be <kbd>FUNCTION</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>. So the whole command is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>FUNCTION</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

i'm using DELL XPS laptop and Ctrl Fn Delete works for me

Answer (score 0):

I lost the server connection (for some reason) and couldn't shut the server down no matter what I tried (CTRL+C etc).

I had to go to the ..AppPath\tmp\pids and renamed the server.pid file.

I then opened CMD and started the server again - that fixed the problem.

Still cannot believe how much hassle it is to just shut the server down... oh dear!

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing the same issue.  I had to open "Task Manager" and manually quit the rudy process to shutdown the server.