# Ctrl-C doesn't work for Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running rails 3.2.1 on windows 7 and I haven't been able to kill my existing server using the Ctrl-C. I have to find it in Task Manager and end the task. I read a few places that this is a bug in Ruby on Rails but didn't see any real fixes. The one solution I did see was to try Ctrl-Pause/Break instead. Unfortunately my laptop doesn't have a Pause/Break key. Any tips would be appreciated.

NOTE: I have tried the other solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660426/rails-server-doesnt-shutdown-with-ctrc-in-windows-7?lq=1) but none of them work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ctrl + Pause break..

Comment: As I stated in the original question, I do not have a Pause/Break button my laptop.